# How can I wake up when push comes in gcm? (cordova hybrid app)

Tags: cordova, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, push, wakeup

I have a few questions for cordova push plugin.

1. When a push notification arrives in the sleep state, the screen does not turn on and only sound is play.
   I want to turn on the screen when push arrive. How can I do that?
2. When a push notification arrives I want to show notification message on center as a popup. But notification messages only show in android status bar.
   Of course, when I pull down the status bar, I can see the message, but I want to show the notification message like a pop in the center. (App is background)
3. I use the phonegap-plugin-push library. 
   Please let me know if there is another cool library that can send push notifications.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**When a push notification arrives in the sleep state, the screen does not turn on and only sound is play. I want to turn on the screen when push arrive. How can I do that?**

- Please try [Setting the priority of a message](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message). Setting a high priority allows a GCM service to wake a sleeping device when possible and open a network connection to your app server.
- For samples using cordova, you may check this [GitHub post](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md).

**When a push notification arrives I want to show notification message on center as a popup.**

- You may want to try using [AlertDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html). If you only want to display a String in this dialog box, use the `setMessage()` method. If you want to display a more complex view, look up the `FrameLayout` called "custom" and add your view to it:

  For more information about creating dialogs, read the [Dialogs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) developer guide.

**I use the phonegap-plugin-push library. Please let me know if there is another cool library that can send push notifications.**

I don't exactly know what you're looking for but you may want to check these (I haven't personally tried though):

- [Catapush Cordova / PhoneGap / Ionic Library](http://www.catapush.com/docs-cordova-phonegap-ionic)
- [Cordova / PhoneGap](http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/cordova-phonegap)
- [cordova-plugin-push-notification-cgvak](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-push-notification-cgvak)

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. I tried your solution, and I finally succeeded in awakening my phone from the notifications. many thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide a tutorial, or just post an answer to your own question to help others?